# How do I use factors in RMARK for known fates analysis?

Tags: r

I want to run models in RMARK for known fates analysis with factors and covariates.

The code I used was:

```
do_analysis=function()
{

S.dot=list(formula=~1)
S.time=list(formula=~time)
S.Sex=list(formula=~Sex)
S.S_ESH=list(formula=~S_ESHerb)

model.list=create.model.list("Known")
Surv.results=mark.wrapper(model.list,data=dp,ddl=ddl,
invisible=FALSE,threads=1)
return(Surv.results)

}

Surv.results=do_analysis()
Surv.results$model.table=model.table(Surv.results,use.lnl=TRUE,model.name=FALSE)
Surv.results
```

I got the error:

```
S.Sex

Error in make.mark.model(data.proc, title = title, parameters = model.parameters,  : 
  The following individual covariates are not allowed because they are factor variables:  Sex
Error in mark(model.parameters = model.parameters, initial = initial,  : 
  Misspecification of model or internal error in code
```

How do I run a model with factors? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define `sex` as a group variable in your model.

Example: `survival.processed <- process.data(data, model="Known",groups=c("sex", "Age"))`